# $\sigma(T)$ is finite $\iff \exists p\in P: p(T) = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

The following is an old exam problem and I can not figure out how to solve it. I have been gathering some facts related to the problem, see below.

#### Problem

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $T: H \to H$ be a compact symmetric linear map. Let $\sigma(T)$ denote the spectrum of $T$ and $P$ the set of polynomials.

1. Prove:  $\sigma(T)$ is finite $\iff \exists p\in P: p(T) = 0$
2. Find a separable Hilbert space $H$ and a compact linear map $C:H\to H$ with finite spectrum such that there is no $p\in P$ with $p(C) = 0$

#### What I know

1. There exists an orthonormal base $\{z_1,z_2,..\}$ for $H$, where $z_i$ are eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to real eigenvalues.
2. $\sigma(T) \subset \{ \lambda : |\lambda| \le |||T||\}$
3. For any $p \in P, \sigma(p(T)) = p(\sigma(T)) $
4. The eigenspace corresponding to any $\lambda \neq 0$ is finite dimensional.
5. For $\lambda \neq 0$, the null spaces of $T_\lambda, T_\lambda^2, T_\lambda^3, ..$ are finite dimensional. ($T_\lambda = T - \lambda I$)

Comment: **Hint:** There are compact non-symmetric operators $B$ with $\sigma(B) = \{0\}$ such that $B^k \ne 0$ for all $k$. *The shift operator on $\ell^2$ would have this property ... but sadly it is non compact ...* But if $B$ is in addition symmetric, this cannot happen.

Comment: But spectrum of shift operator is unit disk (or unit circle for two-sided $l_2$).

Comment: For 1) is 'finite' taken to mean $\sigma(T) $ has finitely many elements? If so could we construct a polynomial which has these points as its zero's? (hint factorization). We then could use the continuous functional calculus to show 1)

Comment: **There  are obvious errors in the question . $0$ is a polynomial and $p(T)=0$ for this $p$ (for any $T$). Also, you need infinite dimesionality. In a f.d. H.S. the identity operator provides a counter-example for the first question if you exclude the zero polynomial.**

Comment: @HansEngler The Volterra operator does the job, it is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Suppose $\sigma(T)$ is finite. Say $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda_j\}_{j=1}^n$. Put $$p(\lambda)=\Pi_j(\lambda-\lambda_j).$$ Then $\sigma(p(T))=p(\sigma(T))=\{0\}$. Note that $T$ is self-adjoint, all $\lambda_j$ are real. This ensure $p(T)$ is self-adjoint. There is an important fact that: for self-adjoint(may not compact) elements $A$, $\|A\|=r(A)$, here $r(A)$ denotes the [Spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$. So $\|p(T)\|=r(p(T))=0$, i.e. $p(T)=0$.
2. Conversly, assume there exists some nonzero polynomial $p$, such that $p(T)=0$. Then $p(\sigma(T))=\sigma(p(T))=\{0\}$, which shows $$\sigma(T)\subseteq Z(p).$$ Here $Z(p)$ denotes the zero set of $p$, which is finite by Fundamental theorem of Algebra.
3. Now we present a compact operator with finite spectrum such that there is no nonzero $p$ with $p(T)=0$. Consider [Volterra operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator) $$V: L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]: f(x) \mapsto \int_0^xf(t)dt.$$ It is indeed Compact, and $\sigma(V)=\{0\}$, of course finite. Note that: $$V^n 1=\frac{1}{n!}x^n.$$
   Polynomials $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ are linear independent. This shows $p(V)1\neq 0$, hence $p(V)\neq 0$